# Ошибка в инициализации локальной переменной

Tags: c, список

Ошибка: error C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "in". Как устранить ошибку?

```
void write_inverse_list(LIST* head)
{
    FILE* in;
    LIST* p;
    fclose(in);

    in = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\in.txt", "w");
    if (head)
    {
        while (head->next)
        {
            p = head;
            fprintf(in, "%s ", p->word);
            head = p->next;
            delete p->word;
            delete p;
        }
        fprintf(in, "%s", head->word);
        delete head->word;
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
    }
        else
        {
         fclose(in);
         in = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\in.txt", "w");
        }
         fclose(in);
}
int main()
{
    LIST* head = NULL;
    head = read_list(head);
    head = osnova(head);
    write_inverse_list(head);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FILE* in;
LIST* p;
fclose(in);
```

Скажите, зачем вы закрываете то, чего **не открывали**? Вот здесь и есть источник проблемы - вы закрываете нечто, что никакого отношения к какому-то файлу не имеет - `in` не имеет никакого значения.

Для того, чтобы устранить *эту конкретную ошибку* - достаточно удалить строку `fclose(in);`.

Еще - все же желательно проверять, что файл открылся, т.е. значение `in` после `fopen`.

И совершенно непонятны вот эти телодвижения -

```
else
{
    fclose(in);
    in = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\in.txt", "w");
}
fclose(in);
```

Зачем? Какой в этом смысл?...